# Are binary predicates sufficient

Tags: predicate-logic

I seem to recall a result that says any set of axioms can be converted to a set of equivalent axioms that use only binary predicates and constants.  Can anyone point me to that result?

Comment: See George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey,[Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=nnAhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA275) (5th e]d - 2007), **Ch.21.3 Dyadic Logic**, page 275.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Do you have a reference by any chance that I can see online

Comment: You can try with the [previous](https://books.google.it/books?id=0LpsXQV2kXAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false) edition (2002).